# This code is not working on online compiler codechef and ideone but tutorialspoint?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner rishu = new Scanner(System.in);
            String str = rishu.nextLine();
            rishu.close();

            URL url = new URL("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1223/0934/files/" + str);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

            String strline;
            int[] x = new int[2];
            int i = 0;
            int sum = 0;

            while ((strline = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(strline + "\n");
            }
            in.close();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your error output?  Even if we were to run your code locally it might not explain why your code does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "Not working" ? Please be specific

Comment: in codechef i am getting error cdn.shopify.com

Comment: in ideone compiler i am getting time limit exceeded error but this code is running well fine in tutorials point online compiler

Comment: please it would be so kind if you try this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is because network access is not allowed in these services.

For example, quote from The [ideone FAQ](https://ideone.com/faq):

> Can I access the Internet from my program?
>
> No, access to the network is blocked.

Comment: [codechef](https://www.codechef.com/ide) sais that it uses [SPOJ](http://www.sphere-research.com/) and it is related to ideone, so I *guess* it should be like ideone.

Comment: i am trying to submit this code in tcs's anyone can code but getting only run time error with 5 tests and not showing the type of error..?  What do i do? sir please help here..this is my major problem.